# How do I turn a string into a class name (without defining it on window)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, brunch, es6-module-loader

`import TestClass from './TestClass'`

How do I reference `TestClass` in this file given the string `'TestClass'`?

`eval('TestClass')` doesn't work because `TestClass is not defined`.

However, if I do `let Test = TestClass`, and then `eval('Test')`, it returns me the constructor for `TestClass`, as desired.

Why does `eval('TestClass')` not work when `eval('Test')` does?

**Context**: 
Given many elements like `<div data-class="TestClass"></div>`, I want to create a generic function that renders the appropriate React components into them. These component classes will be imported into the file before executing this function.

Note: Using Brunch (similar to webpack) as the build system.

Comment: What's your package system? Webpack? Browserify?

Comment: You better reconsider your solution. The whole point of new module system - is that it can be statically analised. Since you cannot `import` dynamically - there is no much point to instantiate dynamically.

Comment: does [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import) help you with what you can and can't achieve?

Comment: @RushyPanchal Using Bruch as the build system

Comment: @JaromandaX Looked at MDN, no luck. I think this is a bit more unconventional

Comment: "a bit more unconventional" --- it's not, it just makes harder to write spaghetti-code.

Comment: "*Why does `eval('TestClass')` not work?*" - it would in a real ES6 environment. It's just that imported variables are transpiled to property accesses on the respective module.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `Brunch` does, but you can just create an object with components after importing and use that to retrieve the component given a string. Something like:

```
import TestClass1 from './TestClass1'
import TestClass2 from './TestClass2'

const componentMap = {
  TestClass1: TestClass1,
  TestClass2: TestClass2
}

// You can just use the map to get the component given the name
const component = componentMap[componentName]
```

Comment: Thanks! This will work. Is there any automated way to define `componentMap` given `['TestClass1', 'TestClass2'] `?

Comment: @AlishanLadhani: No.

Comment: @AlishanLadhani `const componentMap = { TestClass1, TestClass2 };` <- this would be the same but without duplication.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks. Better than duplicating the names. But do I have to write it out by hand? Given an arbitrary length array of strings, can I create `componentMap` with some kind of loop?

Comment: @AlishanLadhani: Why do you start with strings? Start with the classes that you already imported explicitly. Of if you are generating those automatically, just generate the `componentMap` object literal in the same way.